# SendMail in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

```
using System.Net.Mail;

protected void SendMail()
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.google.com");
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 30000;
        SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("recipient@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "test";
        mail.Body = "test";
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;//25
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "pwd");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        //MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have not found any error in my code as per several sources on internet. Still this is not working out.

Comment: The most useless thing to say is _it is not working_ Could you elaborate on what is not working? Any error message?

Comment: @Steve To me, an even more useless thing to do is to catch and swallow exceptions.

Comment: If there are any exceptions please let us know?

Comment: When i uncomment the MessageBox in catch block, the pop-up is coming as "Failure Sending mail"

Comment: and the pop-up keeps on coming.

Comment: Problem resolved. The name of the smtp server should have been smtp.gmail.com. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change you gmail Account Access
Sign in with your Google Account and redirect to this link 
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
Press the Enable, and try your code again
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

In Gmail Use Port-25 and SMTP-smtp.gmail.com

```
  public void mail(string FromEmail, string FromPass, string To, string Tocc, string Tobcc, string subject, string message, string smtpadd, int portnum)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient st = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpadd);
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mst = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mst.To.Add(To);
                if (Tocc != "")
                {
                    mst.CC.Add(Tocc);
                }
                if (Tobcc != "")
                {
                    mst.Bcc.Add(Tobcc);
                }
                mst.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mst.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
                mst.Subject = subject;
                mst.Body = message;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FromEmail, FromPass);
                st.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                st.EnableSsl = true;
                st.Port = portnum;
                st.Credentials = nc;

                st.Send(mst);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Again, an empty-catch-block code snippet! Why on earth do people keep writing and posting such code???